# How to convert French accented words into codes for Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8, locale

I have two versions for my store - English and French. And I am doing the translation from English to French in `app/locale/fr_FR/Mage_Page.csv`

I notice that I have to use some **codes** for certain French characters, such as `En-tÃªte de page` for `tête de page`.

So if I have French words like `100% Magasinage sécurisé`, how can use convert it into **codes** like `En-tÃªte de page`?

Comment: you can use `html number` or `html name` for symbols like `Ãª` `é`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too old without an accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I have a multi-language site (English and French).

In order to display the French characters you need to use [HTML codes](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/codehtml.html)

Using your example:

```
100% Magasinage sécurisé
```

Should be entered as:

```
100% Magasinage s&eacute;curis&eacute;
```

This is for both **php** code and for **CSV** translations.